# Как подключиться к БД 000webhost?

Tags: mysql, golang

Хочу подключиться к БД сайта `000webhost.com`, `id00000_admin:Password123@mydb-night.000webhost.com/id00000_db_name`.

Хостинг `http://mydb-night.000webhost.com/` *(Образно говоря)*, пытался и его впихнуть хостом. Пишет: `panic: default addr for network 'mydb-night.000webhost.com' unknown`

Все данные указаны правильно, вот таблица на самом сайте:

```
DB Name              DB User        DB Host  
id00000_db_name      id00000_admin  localhost
```

Пробовал `localhost, databases-auth.000webhost.com, mydb-night.00webhost.com`.

config.yml:

```
MYSQL:
  data: id00000_admin:Password123@mydb-night.000webhost.com/id00000_db_name
```

Код:

```
var Config = struct {
    Mysql struct {
        Data string `yaml:data`
        Columns string `yaml:columns`
    } `yaml:"MYSQL"`

}{} 

configor.Load(&Config, "config.yml")
var db *sql.DB 
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", Config.Mysql.LoginData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("err connect to db")   
    } else {
        fmt.Println("succ connect to db")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("err connect to db")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("succ ping to db")
    }

    ptable, err := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE minix ( db_int varchar(25), prep_id varchar(25), prep_user text, prep_mpt text, prep_gbt text)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) /*panic err call*/
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Fprintf("err connect to db")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("succ connect to db")
    }

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO minix values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)") 
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("err prepare value")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("succ prepare value")
    }

    main_rows, err := stmt.Exec("152", "good", "adam", "love", "throw")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("fmt err")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("succ insert")
    }
```

Все ровно ошибки: `panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` или `panic: default addr for network 'databases-auth.000webhost.com' unknown`. **Не могу адрес хоста подключения к БД.**

Comment: покажите код, без кода сложно судить.

Comment: @biosckon изменил.

Comment: попробуйте  завернуть URL в [DSN](https://github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL/#dsn-data-source-name) те в конфиг файле `id00000_admin:Password123@tcp(mydb-night.000webhost.com)/id00000_db_name`

Comment: наверное ещё нужно указать правильный порт и убедиться что remote connect вообще работает на этом сервисе, если будет жаловаться что `getsockopt: operation timed out` то порт наверное неверно указан

Comment: если у вас не Premium hosting account то удалённый доступ к mysql отключен